# Excel: Regex to find second, third, etc word in between "/" characters

Tags: regex, excel, replace

I have the following row in excel as an example:

610 323 0726 / 610 332 3855 / LMP90 / LMP106

I have duplicated the column containing these values by 4 so basically I want to find and replace each column so the values are left as below:

column1           | column2            | column3           | column4
610 323 0726    610 332 3855      LMP90              LMP106

I downloaded a regex add-in for excel but I have no idea how to use it and I am not understanding the basics of what to do in general with tutorials. Any help would be great!

Comment: it would help if you indicated what the plugin is called or where to get it, so we may be able to determine the features and limitations of the plugin. Also it's not clear (to me, at least) what you're asking, really.

Comment: The program is called RegEx-Find-Replace..
Don't know how to make it any clearer. I have four values separated by the "/" character. I need to get each value into its own column using regex. There are thousands of rows so I can't do it by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need an add-in? Try using the native `"Text to columns"` functionality

Select column of data then use

Data > Text to columns > delimited > Next > choose "Other" option for delimiter and put / in the box > Next > Finish

Answer (score 0):

Barry's solution is probably the best way.

Yet, it would also very easy to do with VBA if you wanted to add extra checks or additional enhancements:

```
Sub test()
Dim cell As Range
Dim rMyRange As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set rMyRange = Range("A1:A10")
For Each cell In rMyRange
    v = Split(cell.Value, "/")
    With cell
        For i = 0 To UBound(v)
            .Offset(0, i + 1).Value = v(i)
        Next i
    End With
Next cell
End Sub
```